# Error/exception handling (try-catch) C#

Tags: c#

How to achieve the requirements below:

1. **The Retrieve button** click event:

   - if user doesn't enter `CustID` in `txtCustID` need to inform them to enter Customer Id via `lblMessage`;
   - if entered `CustId` doesn't exist in database inform user that it doesn't exist via `lblMessage`.
2. **The Update button** click event - need to ensure that Customer ID already exists in the database.
3. The Delete button click event: same requirements as for Retrieve button.

I must use error/exception handling (`try-catch`) to achieve these (project requirement). I spent hours trying, but no success. I would be very grateful for some help! My code is below:

```
namespace ACME
{
public partial class Customer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["dbConnection1"].ConnectionString);       
    }

    private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie setTheme = Request.Cookies.Get("UserSelectedTheme");
        if (setTheme != null)
        {
            Page.Theme = setTheme.Value;
        }
    }

    protected void Clear()
    {
        txtCustID.Text = "";
        txtFirstname.Text = "";
        txtSurname.Text = "";
        rbtGender.SelectedValue = "";
        txtAge.Text = "";
        txtAddress1.Text = "";
        txtAddress2.Text = "";
        txtCity.Text = "";
        txtPhone.Text = "";
        txtMobile.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtEmail2.Text = "";
    }

    protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();

        Clear();

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["dbConnection1"].ConnectionString);

        command1.Connection = conn;
        command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command1.CommandText = "LargestCustID";
        command1.Connection.Open();

        int id = (int)command1.ExecuteScalar() + 1;
        txtCustID.Text = id.ToString();
        command1.Dispose();
        conn.Close();

    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["dbConnection1"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "AddCustomer";
        command.Connection.Open();

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID",      
         int.Parse(txtCustID.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFirstname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", rbtGender.SelectedValue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", int.Parse(txtAge.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);

        adapter.InsertCommand = command;
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblMessage.Text = "The new record has been added to the database!";

        command.Connection.Close();
        Clear();

    }

    protected void btnRetrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["dbConnection1"].ConnectionString);



        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "GetCustID";
        command.Connection.Open();

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CustID";
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = int.Parse(txtCustID.Text);
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        int id = table.Rows.Count;
        if (id == 0)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Customer ID does not exists!";
        } 
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            txtFirstname.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Firstname");
            txtFirstname.DataBind();
            txtSurname.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Surname");
            txtSurname.DataBind();
            txtAge.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<int>("Age").ToString();
            txtAge.DataBind();
            txtAddress1.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address1");
            txtAddress1.DataBind();
            txtAddress2.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address2");
            txtAddress2.DataBind();
            txtCity.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("City");
            txtCity.DataBind();
            txtPhone.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Phone");
            txtPhone.DataBind();
            txtMobile.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Mobile");
            txtMobile.DataBind();
            txtEmail.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Email");
            txtEmail.DataBind();
        }   

        command.Connection.Close();
    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["dbConnection1"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "UpdateCustomer";
        command.Connection.Open();

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", 
          int.Parse(txtCustID.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFirstname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", rbtGender.SelectedValue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", int.Parse(txtAge.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);

        lblMessage.Text = "The record has been updated!";

        command.Connection.Close();
        Clear();
    }

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["dbConnection1"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "DeleteCustomer";
            command.Connection.Open();


            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@CustID";
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = int.Parse(txtCustID.Text);
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            adapter.DeleteCommand = command;
            adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int id = (int)param.Value;

            command.Connection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text += "Please enter Customer ID!";
        }

        try
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@CustID";
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = int.Parse(txtCustID.Text);
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            adapter.DeleteCommand = command;
            adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int id = table.Rows.Count;
            id = (int)param.Value;

            lblMessage.Text += "Customer record has been deleted";
            command.Connection.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            lblMessage.Text = "Customer ID doesnot exists!";
         } 


        Clear();
    }



    public string CustID { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Would you please post one challenge at a time, not multiple in one question? Also, please clean up your code and make it shorter to highlight  the relevant code elements. There's no need fo irrelevant source code to be posted.

Comment: try catch does not achieve your project requeriments, try -catch is to handle exceptcion in code like connection to database, access to files, etc

Comment: I'm guessing you have to throw an exception when the user does not enter their `CustID`? You should read up on how to use try/catch in C# properly and how to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to control flow of your application by use of exceptions. There are many reasons against this approach:

1) Code is difficult to understand and to debug.

2) Throwing exceptions in .Net is expensive.

3) If exception control flow of application how do you differentiate them from a real exceptions (thrown when something doesn't work as expected)?

If, on the other hand, you want to throw an exception when any of the scenarios you listed in the question happens then you can use standard .Net `Exception` class:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCustID.Text))
{
    throw new Exception("Id not provided.");
}
```

Or you can create a custom exception to provide some more specific information:

```
public class IdNotProvidedException : Exception
{
    public string MyCommandName { get; set; }

    public IdNotProvidedException(string msg)
        : base(msg)
    {

    }

    public IdNotProvidedException(string msg, string myCommandName)
        : base(msg)
    {
        this.MyCommandName = myCommandName;
    }
}
```

And then you initialize and throw your custom exception.

Lastly, there are already places in your code, though not mentioned in your question, that are worth wrapping in a `try...catch` block. Basically, any place where you connect with the server may result in something unexpected (for instance, the server may not be available).